# Fallout 4 Conveyors

Tags: fallout-4

I've spent quite some time putting together a factory in my main settlement.  I've got the manufacturing expanded mod installed and I'm using the recycler as the start point, then some component sorters and some makers (weapon, ammo, auto-loom, faction auto-loom, armour).

However when it's running, I can actually watch as items on the conveyors vanish no where near any of the machines.

Has anyone seen this before and fixed it?  I'm losing a lot of material and it pretty much means I can use the factory.

Comment: Note that I haven't messed around with manufacturing at all: are the items disappearing in the middle of the belt, or at the end? Is it hooked to somewhere? If so, you've confirmed it isn't going there somehow? I mean, it's not just a graphical glitch?

Comment: Hi DCShannon, I'll give that a try.  Just moved house so not been gaming as much.